# Calculo de valores e print de resultado nas células á direita

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macro

Estou a desenvolver uma macro em VBA e necessito de pegar em cada uma das células deste range e passar por uma função select case.

Até aqui tudo bem, o problema é que ele faz vai me calculando os preços e "gravando" por cima ficando em todas as células desse range apenas o último valor.

O que pretendo é para cada uma das células do range (Coluna E) ele vai ler o valor e fazer print do resultado na célula à direita (Coluna F)

Eis o código que tenho até agora:

```
Sub Cal_PV_cal()
Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Application.Range("E1:E237")
Dim rng_out As Range: Set rng_out = Application.Range("F1:F237")

Dim Number As Range

Dim Num_out As Range


'Number = Range("E1:E237").Value    ' Initialize variable.
For Each Number In rng.Cells
    For Each Num_out In rng_out.Cells

        Select Case Number    ' Evaluate Number.
            Case 0 To 1
            Num_out = (Number * 3) * 1.23
            Case 1.001 To 3
            Num_out = (Number * 2.5) * 1.23
            Case 3.001 To 5
            Num_out = (Number * 2) * 1.23
            Case 5.001 To 10
            Num_out = (Number * 1.75) * 1.23
            Case 10.001 To 20
            Num_out = (Number * 1.5) * 1.23
            Case 20.001 To 50
            Num_out = (Number * 1.3) * 1.23
            Case 50.001 To 100000000
            Num_out = (Number * 1.25) * 1.23
            Case Else    ' Other values.
            Num_out = "ERRO"
        
        End Select
        
    Next Num_out
Next Number


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A maneira como você aninhou estes `For Each` faz com que seu programa tenha este comportamento. Para cada célula da entrada seu programa passeia em *todas* as células da saída fazendo o `Select Case` com a entrada atual, por isso mantém a última em todas as saídas.

Para corrigir, controle o qual célula do range de saída será colocado o resultado. No meu caso removi o `For Each` de dentro e usei o `Offset` para definir o destino. Mas não coloquei a validação necessária de que o tamanho do range de entrada e de saída devem ser iguais.

```
Sub Cal_PV_cal()
Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Application.Range("E1:E237")
Dim rng_out As Range: Set rng_out = Application.Range("F1:F237")

Dim Number As Range
Dim Num_out As Range
Dim i As Long
i = 0

For Each Number In rng.Cells
    'Pega celula correspondente no range de saida
    Set Num_out = rng_out(1, 1).Offset(i, 0)

        Select Case Number    ' Evaluate Number.
            Case 0 To 1
            Num_out = (Number * 3) * 1.23
            Case 1.001 To 3
            Num_out = (Number * 2.5) * 1.23
            Case 3.001 To 5
            Num_out = (Number * 2) * 1.23
            Case 5.001 To 10
            Num_out = (Number * 1.75) * 1.23
            Case 10.001 To 20
            Num_out = (Number * 1.5) * 1.23
            Case 20.001 To 50
            Num_out = (Number * 1.3) * 1.23
            Case 50.001 To 100000000
            Num_out = (Number * 1.25) * 1.23
            Case Else    ' Other values.
            Num_out = "ERRO"
        
        End Select
        
    'Próximo i
    i = i + 1
Next Number


End Sub
```